# show name of the user on hover on material ui Avatar component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hi i have a profile page in my website and i am displaying the image of the profile holder using the material-ui Avatar component i want to show the name of the profile holder in the center of avatar and the sample code is given blow

```
        <div {...otherProps} style={{ display: 'block', margin: 'auto' }}>
            <StyledBadge
                overlap="circular"
                anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: 'bottom',
                    horizontal: 'right',
                }}
                variant={showBadge ? "dot" : "standard"}
            >
                <Avatar alt="avatar" src={src || defaultImg} className={clsx(classes.avatar, classes[size])} />
            </StyledBadge>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why can't you just use [Tooltip](https://mui.com/components/tooltips/#main-content) component?

Comment: i dont know how it works

Comment: do i need to import it from the core?

Comment: Which version of the Material UI are you using?

Comment: i am using version 4

Comment: Apart from the tooltip (which mentioned in the answer below), you can also use the [title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) attribute as well. The information provided in the `title` is most often shown as a `tooltip` on hover. Although, `tooltip` component on the MUI has more options out of box, if your use case is more then just a simple text. [title demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Tooltip` component from MUI:

```
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";

...

<Tooltip title={userName}>
  <Avatar src={userProfilePicture}></Avatar>
</Tooltip>
```

See also [Tooltip material doc page](https://mui.com/components/tooltips/#main-content)

[Codesandbox exemple](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictooltip-material-demo-forked-lcrkm?file=/demo.js)

Comment: working in desktop mode but not in mobile mod

Comment: your Codesandbox doesn't work.

Comment: but your solution is also not working for the mobile mode

Comment: hover state doesn't exist on mobile